# SortUsingDescriptors turns NSMutableArray with NSMutableDictionaries immutable

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary, nssortdescriptor

Is there any way around this? Here is my code, this works but if I move the "setObject:YES forKey:" below sortUsingDescriptor, I get "mutating method sent to immutable object"

```
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy"];
    for (NSMutableDictionary *tempDict in tweetArray){
        NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tempDict valueForKey:@"created_at"]]];
        NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [date timeIntervalSince1970]];

        NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:tempDict];
        [newDict setValue:dateString forKey:@"created_time"];
        [newDict setValue:@"twitter" forKey:@"network"];
        [combinedPosts addObject:newDict];
    }
    for (NSMutableDictionary *tempDict in instagramArray){
        [combinedPosts addObject:tempDict];
    }

    [[combinedPosts objectAtIndex:0] setObject:@"yes" forKey:@"isDownloadingPhoto"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortByDate = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"created_time" ascending:NO];
    [combinedPosts sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortByDate, nil]];
```

Comment: What evidence do you have that combinePosts is immutable?  Did you NSLog its class?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using setValue inside the for loop and setObject outside.  At this point you are trying to essentially add a "isDownloadingPhoto" key with value "yes" to a pre-existing dictionary?

Comment: Iv'e seen this before, and I think what it really is complaining about is the fact you are sending a static string value in when the routine is expecting a living object (if you will).

Comment: @HotLicks because it gives me the "mutating method sent to immutable object" and when I add an exception breakpoint, it points to the setObject line. Also, when I move the setObject line above sortUsingDescriptor, I don't get the exception.

Comment: @trumpetlicks inside the for loop I am adding a timestamp and what network it belongs to. outside the for loop I am trying to add a BOOL to the dict (that is not where I am really using setObject but i have it there for debugging)

Comment: But the setObject line is before the sort.  What evidence do you have that the object in the array was mutable?  (And simply being assigned from a variable that's typed as mutable doesn't count.)

Comment: @trumpetlicks sorry I miss read. I don't have a reason why Im using setValue and setObject. I wrote setValue a while ago. Is one of them preferred?

Comment: @HotLicks sorry, I didn't realize I posted it with the setObject line above the sort. When is like that, it is fine. When I move it below, I get the exception. And it's all mutable because I create nsmutabledictionaries from the JSON that instagram and twitter return

Comment: Note that when you sort you change the order of the elements (duh!).  What was element 0 may no longer be element 0.  And we have no way of knowing that the elements coming out of instagramArray are mutable.

Comment: When something isn't working as expected, break long chains of code into components so you can debug.  In this case extract objectAtIndex:0 into a temp and operate on the temp with setObject.  And log the class of the temp while you're at it.

Comment: Yeah but I don't care about the order. I am just trying to add that key to the first in combinedPosts

Comment: Read my comment 2 minutes ago.  What's coming out of instagramArray????

Comment: the instagramArray is an array of mutable dictionaries

Comment: I logged the class and its NSArrayM so it still is a mutable array, so what would be causing this? Something happens after sorting it

Comment: You logged which class?

Comment: Not instagramArray, but the elements inside instagramArray.  You're trying to modify a dictionary entry that came out of that array.

Comment: (And what is the *actual* error message you're getting -- you should be getting "unrecognized selector".)

Comment: I just read your comments.  The problem is that you aren't adding t bool yes, you are adding a string "yes"!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken. sortUsingDescriptors operates in place on a mutable array. The method "sortedArrayUsingDescriptors" creates a new, immutable array with the sorted contents of the receiver.

In both methods, the objects being sorted will be unchanged. (If they are mutable they will still be mutable after sorting.)

Comment: That's not his problem.  The function he is using is indeed defined in the NSMutableArray object, and thus it should not be immuting it array.  The problem is with the element.  He is attempting to modify the element with key "isDownloadingPhoto".  I don't see the code that shows his creation of that element within the dictionary.